# CPU bound/stateful distributed system design

Tags: amazon-ec2, rabbitmq, activemq-classic, distributed-computing, zeromq

I'm working on a web application frontend to a legacy system which involves a lot of CPU bound background processing. The application is also stateful on the server side and the domain objects needs to be held in memory across the entire session as the user operates on it via the web based interface. Think of it as something like a web UI front end to photoshop where each filter can take 20-30 seconds to execute on the server side, so the app still has to interact with the user in real time while they wait.

The main problem is that each instance of the server can only support around 4-8 instances of each "workspace" at once and I need to support a few hundreds of concurrent users at once. I'm going to be building this on Amazon EC2 to make use of the auto scaling functionality. So to summarize, the system is:

- A web application frontend to a legacy backend system
- task performed are CPU bound
- Stateful, most calls will be some sort of RPC, the user will make multiple actions that interact with the stateful objects held in server side memory
- Most tasks are semi-realtime, where they have to execute for 20-30 seconds and return the results to the user in the same session
- Use amazon aws auto scaling

I'm wondering what is the best way to make a system like this distributed.

Obviously I will need a web server to interact with the browser and then send the cpu-bound tasks from the web server to a bunch of dedicated servers that does the background processing. The question is how to best hook up the 2 tiers together for my specific neeeds.

I've been looking at message Queue systems such as rabbitMQ but these seems to be geared towards one time task where any worker node can simply grab a job form a queue, execute it and forget the state. My needs are a little different since there could be multiple 'tasks' that needs to be 'sticky', for example if step 1 is started in node 1 then step 2 for the same workspace has to go to the same worker process.

Another problem I see is that most worker queue systems seems to be geared towards background tasks that can be processed anytime rather than a system that has to provide user feedback that I'm dealing with.

My question is, is there an off the shelf solution for something like this that will allow me to easily build a system that can scale? Would love to hear your thoughts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- RabbitMQ is has an [RPC tutorial](http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-python.html). I haven't used this pattern in particular but I am running RabbitMQ on a couple of nodes and it can handle hundreds of connections and millions of messages. With a little work in monitoring you can detect when there is more work to do then you have consumers for. Messages can also timeout so queues won't backup too greatly. To scale out capacity you can create multiple RabbitMQ nodes/clusters. You could have multiple rounds of RPC so that after the first response you include the information required to get second message to the correct destination.
- 0MQ has this as a [basic pattern](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page%3aall#advanced-request-reply) which will fanout work as needed. I've only played with this but it is simpler to code and possibly simpler to maintain (as it doesn't *need* a broker, `devices` can provide one though). This may not handle stickiness by default but it should be possible to write your own routing layer to handle it.
- Don't discount HTTP for this as well. When you want request/reply, a strict throughput per backend node, and something that scales well, HTTP is well supported. With AWS you can use their ELB easily in front of an autoscaling group to provide the routing from frontend to backend. ELB supports [sticky sessions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/US_StickySessions.html) as well.

I'm a big fan of RabbitMQ but if this is the whole scope then HTTP would work nicely and have fewer moving parts in AWS than the other solutions.